# Installing Docker under Digital Ocean which urls to use?

Tags: docker, digital-ocean

I want to install my laravel 5 app under docker on ubuntu 18 server under Digital Ocean, looking into article
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04
I created images successfully and checked logs : no errors. Also vendor directory was created in my app directory.

I check port output :

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
0c25fa607a2f        adminer              "entrypoint.sh docke…"   About a minute ago   Up 59 seconds       0.0.0.0:8086->8080/tcp   youtubeapidemo_adminer_1
0b2b4dd045d9        mysql:5.5.62         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   3306/tcp                 youtubeapidemo_db_1
b854e4e6d68e        youtubeapidemo_web   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8085->80/tcp     youtubeapidemo_web_1
2719b05a1078        composer:1.6         "/bin/sh /docker-ent…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                            youtubeapidemo_composer_1
```

On my local server when I need to enter my site page or adminer I used urls

```
http://127.0.0.1:8085/public
```

or

```
http://127.0.0.1:8086
```

but which url have I to use on under Digital Ocean, as ip of my server is NNN.NN.NNN.NN ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://NNN.NN.NNN.NN:8085` for the Youtube API demo container.